# How to modify a trained SentencePiece tokenizer to stop splitting the chatml tokens?

Tags: tokenize, sentencepiece, nltokenizer

We are using a pre-trained SentencePiece tokenizer (the SentencePiece tokenizer from Google, not huggingface), and we would like to preserve the `chatML` tokens:

`<|im_start|>` and `<|im_end|>`

We don't want to split the tokens, and we want the tokenizer to map them to separate values.

`sp_model = SentencePieceProcessor(model_file=...)`

Using the python implementation, how should we modify the model to do this? Thanks!